# Extract string not between parentheses

Tags: php, string

I have a string like `"which I want (which I don't want)"`, here using php I want to extract only `"which I want"`.

So I want to exclude the string enclosed in parenthesis `(which I do not want)` in my result string.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$val = "which I want (which I don't want)";
reg_replace('/((.*))/', '', $val);
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried and explain what does not work.

Comment: `explode("(", $s)[0]`

Comment: Clarified question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. Since the parenthesis are special characters in regular expressions, you have to escape them in order for it to work:

```
preg_replace('/(\s?\(.*\))/', '', $val);
```

`(` and `)` are group delimiters in RegEx, whereas `\(` and `\)` are literal parenthesis.

I also added an optional whitespace before the parenthesis so you get rid of that too.

Comment: The optional whitespace can also be solved by trimming the string after the replace.

Comment: I was just trying to stick with the function intended by the OP ;)